# changing content for multiple iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have some project that need to change multiple iframe with some array
example

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <iframe src="test.html">
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div class="content">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </iframe>
  </li>
  <li>
    <iframe src="test.html">
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div class="content">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </iframe>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to change `<div class="content"><p>test</p></div>` for each `iframe` with an array `["<h1>tittle</h1>","<h1>tittle2</h1>"]`.

For the first iframe it will be replaced with the HTML in `array[0]` and second iframe with `array[1]`.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
var array = ["<h1>tittle</h1>", "<h1>tittle2</h1>"]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').each(function(a) {
      $(this).contents().find('body').children('.content').replaceWith(array[a]);
    })
  })

})
```

Comment: thanks for the pointing it's almost solve just need to change little bit on my project

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
var arr = ["<h1>tittle</h1>","<h1>tittle2</h1>"];
var found=0;
$('iframe').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('.content p').length > 0){
    $(this).find('.content p').parent().replaceWith(arr[found]);
    found++;
  }
});
```

It searches for every iframe, then checks if it contains the tags you want, then replaces them with your array's replacement.

The variable 'found' allows you to travel through the array.

Answer (score 0):

As much as you tagged your post with "jQuery", I suppose you can use this library.
So you just need to iterate over the `.each()` function.

```
var array = ["<h1>tittle</h1>","<h1>tittle2</h1>"];
$(".content").each(function(i) {
    $(this).html(array[i]);
});
```

You can obviously replace `html()` with `replaceWith()` if you really want to delete the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var iframe = $('iframe');
for (i=0; i<iframe.length; i++){
 var current = $('iframe')[i+1].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
 $('iframe')[i].contents().find('html').html(current); 
}
```